# Aligning Text within a List with Different Length Text to Start Each Line

Tags: align, lists

For my discrete structures class I often find myself creating lists which contain equations or propositional statements, with a description needed on the same line but further to the right. I want to align all of the descriptions even though the equations or propositions may all be different lengths. I have not seen any solutions to alignment issues that apply to this specific problem. The image below shows what I am looking for along with the issue (I've manually aligned the first 7 lines with \hspace{} but would like an easier solution as you can see that even doing it manually doesn't line up perfectly).

[image]

Comment: you could put each formula in `\makebox[.3\textwidth][l]{$\forall....}`

Comment: If you search hard enough you'll find packages for Lemmon-style natural deduction proofs like [nd](https://phloxgroup.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/nd-manual2.pdf), which may fit your needs. For some reason they're not on CTAN though. There are fitch style packages on CTAN, which is slightly differently. You could also just use a customized tabular or tabbing environment, with a custom counter and `>{\refstepcounter{proofline}}` or whatever in the colspec. I'll give more details if you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may absorb the material suitably input like in tabular format and measure the column widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{formalproof}{b}
 {
  \begin{flushleft}
  \linespread{1.2}\selectfont
  \james_formalproof:n { #1 }
  \end{flushleft}
 }
 {}

\seq_new:N \l__james_formalproof_body_seq
\seq_new:N \l__james_formalproof_tmp_seq
\dim_new:N \l__james_formalproof_left_dim
\dim_new:N \l__james_formalproof_right_dim
\dim_new:N \l__james_formalproof_step_dim
\int_new:N \l__james_formalproof_line_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \james_formalproof:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__james_formalproof_body_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  % check for a trailing \\
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__james_formalproof_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VF \l_tmpa_tl
   {% the last item is not empty, restore it
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__james_formalproof_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
   }
  % now let's compute the item widths
  \dim_zero:N \l__james_formalproof_left_dim
  \dim_zero:N \l__james_formalproof_right_dim
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__james_formalproof_body_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__james_formalproof_tmp_seq { & } { ##1 }
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { $\seq_item:Nn \l__james_formalproof_tmp_seq { 1 }$ }
    \dim_set:Nn \l__james_formalproof_left_dim
     {
      \dim_max:nn { \l__james_formalproof_left_dim } { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
     }
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpb_box { (\seq_item:Nn \l__james_formalproof_tmp_seq { 2 }) }
    \dim_set:Nn \l__james_formalproof_right_dim
     {
      \dim_max:nn { \l__james_formalproof_right_dim } { \box_wd:N \l_tmpb_box }
     }
   }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \seq_count:N \l__james_formalproof_body_seq }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__james_formalproof_step_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
  % now we can process the whole thing
  \int_zero:N \l__james_formalproof_line_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__james_formalproof_body_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__james_formalproof_tmp_seq { & } { ##1 }
    \int_incr:N \l__james_formalproof_line_int
    \par
    \makebox[\l__james_formalproof_step_dim][r]
     { \int_to_arabic:n { \l__james_formalproof_line_int } }.\enspace
    \makebox[\l__james_formalproof_left_dim][l]
     { $\seq_item:Nn \l__james_formalproof_tmp_seq { 1 }$ }
    \hfill
    \makebox[\l__james_formalproof_right_dim][l]
     { (\seq_item:Nn \l__james_formalproof_tmp_seq { 2 }) }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\begin{formalproof}
\exists x \overline{A(x)} & premise \\
\overline{A(a)} & existential instantiation \\
\forall x(C(x)\to\overline{D(x)}) & premise \\
C(a)\to\overline{D(a)} & universal instantiation \\
\overline{C(a)}\lor \overline{D(a)} & definition \\
\forall x(\overline{B(x)}\lor D(x)) & premise \\
\overline{B(a)}\lor D(a) & universal instantiation \\
\overline{C(a)}\lor\overline{B(a)} & resolution 5+7 \\
\forall x(A(x)\lor B(x)) & premise
\end{formalproof}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\begin{formalproof}
\exists x \overline{A(x)} & premise \\
\overline{A(a)} & existential instantiation \\
\forall x(C(x)\to\overline{D(x)}) & premise \\
C(a)\to\overline{D(a)} & universal instantiation \\
\overline{C(a)}\lor \overline{D(a)} & definition \\
\forall x(\overline{B(x)}\lor D(x)) & premise \\
\overline{B(a)}\lor D(a) & universal instantiation \\
\overline{C(a)}\lor\overline{B(a)} & resolution 5+7 \\
\forall x(A(x)\lor B(x)) & premise \\
A+B+C & just one more line \\
\end{formalproof}

\lipsum[4][1-3]

\end{document}
```

In the second example you see two things: the width reserved for the numbers is taken care of; also, a trailing `\\` has no effect.

[image]

Note that this allows for page breaks in a formal proof. Another approach would be to use `tabular*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{formalproof}{b}
 {
  \james_formalproof:n { #1 }
 }
 {}

\seq_new:N \l__james_formalproof_body_seq
\int_new:N \g__james_formalproof_line_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \james_formalproof:n
 {
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__james_formalproof_body_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  % check for a trailing \\
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__james_formalproof_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VF \l_tmpa_tl
   {% the last item is not empty, restore it
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__james_formalproof_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
   }
  % process the material in a tabular*
  \int_gzero:N \g__james_formalproof_line_int
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}
   {
    >{
      \int_gincr:N \g__james_formalproof_line_int
      \int_to_arabic:n { \g__james_formalproof_line_int }
      .
    }r
    @{\hspace{0.5em}}
    >{$}l<{$}
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    >{(}l<{)}
    @{}
   }
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__james_formalproof_body_seq \__james_formalproof_line:n
  \end{tabular*}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__james_formalproof_line:n { & #1 \\ }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\begin{center}
\begin{formalproof}
\exists x \overline{A(x)} & premise \\
\overline{A(a)} & existential instantiation \\
\forall x(C(x)\to\overline{D(x)}) & premise \\
C(a)\to\overline{D(a)} & universal instantiation \\
\overline{C(a)}\lor \overline{D(a)} & definition \\
\forall x(\overline{B(x)}\lor D(x)) & premise \\
\overline{B(a)}\lor D(a) & universal instantiation \\
\overline{C(a)}\lor\overline{B(a)} & resolution 5+7 \\
\forall x(A(x)\lor B(x)) & premise
\end{formalproof}
\end{center}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\begin{center}
\begin{formalproof}
\exists x \overline{A(x)} & premise \\
\overline{A(a)} & existential instantiation \\
\forall x(C(x)\to\overline{D(x)}) & premise \\
C(a)\to\overline{D(a)} & universal instantiation \\
\overline{C(a)}\lor \overline{D(a)} & definition \\
\forall x(\overline{B(x)}\lor D(x)) & premise \\
\overline{B(a)}\lor D(a) & universal instantiation \\
\overline{C(a)}\lor\overline{B(a)} & resolution 5+7 \\
\forall x(A(x)\lor B(x)) & premise \\
A+B+C & just one more line \\
\end{formalproof}
\end{center}

\lipsum[4][1-3]

\end{document}
```

The output is essentially the same as before.

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you.